# Show description of error iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, error-handling

Is there any command which shows the decription of the error on xcode console. When we debug the application and if there is some error on the console and i want to see the error decription. Tell me the command. 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean an NSError object, you can use the following:

```
NSLog(@"Bummer: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

Comment: but also there is one commandd...i am not sure but its like bw

Comment: If you mean in the gdb prompt then you can type "po error" or "po [error localizedDescription]" - po is short for the print object command in gdb